# What would a life form that evolved in deep space and without gravity look like?

Tags: evolution, aliens, space-travel, stars, origin-of-life

Somehow the following hypothetical life form evolved in deep space with a long lifetime. It lives in a low orbit around massive stars, reproduces by eating interstellar gas and dust and uses the energy from the star to stay alive.

When the star begins to die, this lifeforms migrates to another one propelling itself with the rest of the collected energy.

Taking in account how it lives. Can withstand high radiation and heat, can live for a long time without food, Can travel astronomical distances only with its stored energy.

- What would its evolved body look like?

  - is it organic?
  - what shape and size such creatures may have?
  - How they absorb energy?
  - Which kind of propulsion they may use.

Comment: Secespitus, the life form did not evolve "on a planet with zero-G". The question says that it has never touched a planet, and how can a planet have zero G anyways? :)

Comment: This is now less opinion-based, but it's still an idea generation question which are closed as `too broad`. Not only that, but the question asks 8 questions instead of 1, which would also get it hit with a `too broad` closure.

Comment: Where is "deep space"?

Comment: I meant space between stars, were is nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to answer unequivocally to such a question, but Fred Hoyle tried in [The Black Cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Black_Cloud) (1957).

His star hopping entity was actually a kind of mega-computer whose electronic was etched on the surface of billions rocks composing a "black cloud" (whence the title). These separate parts would participate, being connected by wireless, to compose the intelligent being.

Other schemes are possible, of course, but I find this particularly fascinating... which isn't strange given the [author](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fred_Hoyle).

Comment: The original idea for a creature like Hoyle's black cloud came from Thomas Gold who was a creative physicist, friend and colleague of Hoyle. The novel suggests the black cloud might either a single collective intelligence or a population of intelligent beings sharing the cloud. Hoyle was prepared to challenge scientific orthodoxy, which did lead him into backing some silly ideas. Interestingly some of his ideas, but not all, though in different forms, are becoming scientifically acceptable. An amusing irony.